# Apache: deny acces to directory but allow 1 file

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, hosts.allow

I am using Apache 2.2.22 on Ubuntu 12.04.

I need to disable access to directory `/var/www/abc/` but allow access to file inside this directory `/var/www/abc/README.txt`. I try:

```
<Directory /var/www/abc/*>
    Order allow,deny
    deny from all
    <Files /var/www/abc/README.txt>
        order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

But it doens't work - acess to directory is disabled (ok) and file is to disabled (not ok).

What I do bad?

Comment: Try to move `<Files>` outside of `<Directory>`

Comment: I tried move Files outside Directory and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files tag must use relative path to Directory. With absolute path (`<Files /var/www/abc/README.txt>`) it doesn't work.

This works:

```
<Directory /var/www/abc/*>
    Order allow,deny
    deny from all
    <Files README.txt>
        order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Files>
</Directory>
```